# Can I use the same Monero miner on a 32bit and 64bit os?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm mining Monero with my raspberry pi and everything's working just fine. Now I found out that the original (by the raspberry community/devs) os (Raspbian) is only 32bit... To increase my RPis performance I want to install [Pi64](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64) on it (obviously an 64bit os).

At the moment I'm using the xmrig miner for mining Monero...

My questions is if I could install and compile xmrig on a 64bit os just as I did on my 32bit os or could there be some issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling and installing xmrig on a 64 bit OS will work fine.